# Get optGroup id from selected option in select2

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-select2

How can I get `id` from `optgroup` when child element is selected? 
For example if you have this kind of JSON used for creating `select2`:

```
var data = [{ 
    id: p0, 
    text: 'enhancement',
    children: [{
        id: c5,
        text: 'enhancement child1'
    },{
        id: c6,
        text: 'enhancement child2'
    }]
},{ 
    id: c1, 
    text: 'bug' 
},{ 
    id: c2, 
    text: 'duplicate' 
},{ 
    id: c3, 
    text: 'invalid' 
},{ 
    id: c4, 
    text: 'wontfix' 
}];
```

And using `$("#select2").val();` will only retrieve ids from selected items, so in which way all of the parents `optgroups` ids can be retrieved? (for selected `enhancement child1` item, returned data is `id=c5` and `id=p0`)

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/rfn5p18x)

Any suggestion and directions how this can be solved?

Comment: Created fiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/rfn5p18x/

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to collect. Could you clarify what you're trying to do or accomplish more.

Comment: for selected enhancement child1 item, returned data is id=c5 and id=p0 (as i describe in main post)

Comment: The Event does not return the parent `id`, nor is it in the `optgroup` tag in the code. It's not clear where this value is. See tests: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/rfn5p18x/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my research, there is not a direct way to collect the `optgroup` id when the a selection is made.Here is the resulting HTML:

```
<select class="js-example-data-array select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">    
    <optgroup label="enhancement">
        <option value="c5">enhancement child1</option>
        <option value="c6">enhancement child2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="c1">bug</option>
    <option value="c2">duplicate</option>
    <option value="c3">invalid</option>
    <option value="c4">wontfix</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**

Upon further inspection, the DOM for `html body.forceShow select.js-example-data-array.select2-hidden-accessible optgroup` does have a `value` of `p0`. Still trying to find out how to gather this based on the specific selection.

You can add this detail into the data and then you can get it out. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/rfn5p18x/4/

**HTML**

```
<select class="js-example-data-array">
</select>
<select class="js-example-data-array-selected">
  <option value="2" selected="selected">duplicate</option>
</select>
<div id="results">
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
var data = [{
  id: 'p0',
  text: 'enhancement',
  children: [{
    id: 'c5',
    text: 'enhancement child1',
    parent: 'p0'
  }, {
    id: 'c6',
    text: 'enhancement child2',
    parent: 'p0'
  }]
}, {
  id: 'c1',
  text: 'bug'
}, {
  id: 'c2',
  text: 'duplicate'
}, {
  id: 'c3',
  text: 'invalid'
}, {
  id: 'c4',
  text: 'wontfix'
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-data-array").select2({
    data: data
  });
  $(".js-example-data-array").on("select2:select", function(e) {
    if (e.params.data.parent.length) {
      console.log(e.params.data.parent + " > " + e.params.data.id + " selected");
    } else {
      console.log(e.params.data.id + " selected");
    }
  });
  $(".js-example-data-array-selected").select2({
    data: data
  });
});
```

You can see now the data contains a reference to the parent and can now be accessed when an option is selected. It will not be available under `.val()` but you could deposit it elsewhere when selected or modify the `.val()` to include it.

**EDIT FIXED**

Was able to gather the `optgroup` id from `$("option:selected").parent("optgroup").val();`. Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/rfn5p18x/7/

**JQuery**

```
var data = [{
  id: 'p0',
  text: 'enhancement',
  children: [{
    id: 'c5',
    text: 'enhancement child1',
  }, {
    id: 'c6',
    text: 'enhancement child2',
  }]
}, {
  id: 'c1',
  text: 'bug'
}, {
  id: 'c2',
  text: 'duplicate'
}, {
  id: 'c3',
  text: 'invalid'
}, {
  id: 'c4',
  text: 'wontfix'
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-data-array").select2({
    data: data
  });
  $(".js-example-data-array").on("select2:select", function(e) {
    var pID = $("option:selected").parent("optgroup").val();
    if (typeof pID !== "undefined") {
      $("#results").append("Parent: " + pID + "<br />\r\n");
    }
    $("#results").append("Value: " + $(this).val() + "<br />\r\n");
  });

  $(".js-example-data-array-selected").select2({
    data: data
  });
});
```

Comment: This will do the job, but its not the right way of doing. Thanks.

Comment: ... Okay what is the Right way?

Comment: Right way is to be get from optgroup, and not to be set on **every** item that is inserted in select(there can be a lot of items under the same optgroup and the same id will be repeated and that is not the right way)

Comment: Take a look at my Edit in the answer. Not easily obtained, yet it may be possible.

Comment: Got it: `var pID = $("option:selected").parent("optgroup").val();`

Comment: Note that you can get the selected data objects using `.select2('data')` (as a getter) instead of always having to listen to the `select2:select` event.

Comment: @Twisty: When having multiple select2 initialized this resulted in always reading the first one. The solution for me was the following: `$(this).find('option:selected').parent("optgroup").val()`

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to do is add an `extra field` to the children object and store the `group id` in it.

You can retrieve the extra field by `e.params.data.extra`.

You can name the field as you want.

**Example below:**

```js
const data = [
    {
        id: "gp1",
        text: "group1",
        children: [
            { id: "c1", text: " child1", extra: "gp1" },
            { id: "c2", text: " child2", extra: "gp1" },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "gp2",
        text: "group2",
        children: [
            { id: "c3", text: " child3", extra: "gp2" },
            { id: "c4", text: " child4", extra: "gp2" },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "c5",
        text: "child5",
    },
];

$("select").select2({
    width: "80%",
    data: data,
});

$("select").on("select2:select", function (e) {
    console.log("group name:", e.params.data.extra);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select multiple>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```